# How to find out which plugin is blocking user?

Tags: plugins

A remote user is telling me she can't get into the site. Upon trying to log in, she is getting an error message shown below. I am able to log into her account from my end. I thought this was either Wordfence or iThemes security plugins blocking it. But I deactivated both plugins and she is still having issue logging in.

Does anybody know what plugin is creating this problem and why? I get that her IP somehow got blocked, but I need to know which plugin blocked it in order to take care of that.

"Access Blocked
Allow Request

You have been blocked from entering information on this site. In order to prevent this from pahhening in the future, complete the request below to have the admin add your IP to a list that allows you full accesss."

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Take turns disabling the plugins and getting her to try and access.  Depending on your host this may even be a Must Use plugin they drop into your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. It was the Stop Spammer Registration plugin. The way I figured it out is I did a text search in the wordpress directory. This found one file containing some of that error's wording. I looked up the plugin by the folder name the file was in.

```
sudo grep -rnw './' -e 'You have been blocked from entering information on this site. In order to prevent this from'
```

Comment: A user also received this error from our website.  This help identify where it was coming from.